# Windows Integrated Authentication not working on first page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 website deployed on IIS with Windows Authentication enabled. My config file has this setting:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

My understanding is that this will allow me to authenticate without having to type in credentials; i.e. an intranet site.

This works as intended, except for the first page load. When I first access the website, I am directed to the following URL:

> http://localhost/SandboxWebsite/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fSandboxWebsite

This is obviously a page that asks for credentials. When I then navigate again to `http://localhost/SandboxWebsite/`, I am automatically authenticated without having to enter any credentials.

Why is this occurring and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that, whilst anonymous access was disabled as a setting, there was no authorisation *rule* to deny anonymous users. Why this redirected me to Login.aspx I do not know, but I fixed it by adding the following rules.

IIS > MyWebsite > .NET Authorization Rules

[image]

Answer (score 1):

John,

this is a long shot but have you tried using an address other than LocalHost to access the site ? It may be that your ASP.NET MVC4 website is expecting a specific domain name/computer name or IP address because of the way it was setup.

You could alter your hosts file to test this out.

Hope this helps.
Dorje

Comment: Hi Dorje, I actually managed to fix this. I will answer the question myself when I get some time. The input is appreciated though!